# Issue with Google AJAX crawling, returning the snapshot URL's instead of the hashbang URL's

Tags: ajax, apache, seo

I've just implemented ajax crawling, and my URL is: http://acs-germany.de/#!en/homepage
The site just got indexed, and I'm looking at the search results here:
https://www.google.at/#hl=en&q=+site:acs-germany.de+acs-germany.de

You'll notice that the URL that got indexed contains "fragments" . This is a folder that is present on my system and contains the HTML snapshots of "ajax" (or better, dhtml) content. When following that URL, the snapshot is served, which in turn breaks the app as the app is instantiated on top of a half-baked markup, making the site FUBAR.

I'm using apache, and my rules relevant to URL rewriting are as follows:

```
Options -MultiViews
#Rewrite queries from google to the right files
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://acs-germany.de/fragments/%1.html?
```

To be straight:
The site lives at http://acs-germany.de , when JS is active it sets a hashbang pointing the browser's location to http://acs-germany.de/#!en/homepage  .
To this extent I'm expecting that the url with hashbangs is what gets indexed by google, rather than the rewritten URL.

What may be the issue here?

Comment: Further research indicated that i forgot the following in my html page: <meta name="fragment" content="!"> . i will now have to wait until the page gets re-indexed to see if that was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Your files in the fragment folder are indexable so if Google finds them they will get indexed.

Google will check the _escaped_fragment_= version of your URL to get the content. You are 302 redirecting that to the fragments folder version.

That's not what your .htaccess code implies. Is there a [R] you are not telling us about?

I suspect that redirect is confusing Google's system and they end up indexing your fragments folder files.

I suggest you simplify things and do exactly what Google asks. The _escaped_fragment_= URL should directly return the basic content for the page.

Then you may want to 301 redirect those fragments folder files back to the #! versions to encourage Google to index the right stuff.

To be honest I do not see any reason to make this website AJAX based. Each click seems to fully recreate the page. AJAX is about only updating parts of a page.

Comment: Thanks for your input. There is no [R] i am not telling you about, and I honestly cant think of how to simplify this: i have a rewrite rule, that detects a request to that and serves a physical file. I cannot make the _escaped_fragment_ a physical file since its part of a query parameter. Regarding "why" this is made with JS, its because thats what i like doing and there is no real reason to get into the specifics of this. Pardon but i dont quite get your suggestion, could you try explaining it again? Thanks

Comment: It is also to be said that the website is hosted by a @#%@ of an ISP. my first attempt at adding the rewrite rules failed on their infrastructure, but worked on mine. who knows what else they're doing behind the curatins.

Comment: You can make any URL look like a physical file. Your .htaccess code looks like it should do that. It should not redirect but just return the content directly. But it is redirecting!

This is where I would start testing by elimination. Remove things and see how it behaves. Is that code controlling it. If it's removed are redirects still happening. Is MultiViews involved. Is there other code in there that may affect things. What happens if you completely remove the file etc.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I fixed it removing the http:// part from the RewriteRule. Try this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /acs-germany.de/fragments/%1.html?
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /fragments/%1.html?
```

Having http:// caused Apache to "redirect" instead of "rewrite" the URL